# How to concatenate a value from a table to a string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

I have a stored procedure that currently uses a hard coded mail server. It should instead use the value stored in a table. It currently looks like this

```
select @myQuery = 'c:\folder\mailto.exe -H mail.here.com -U sender.sample.com -D receiver@sample.com'
```

I have tried this:

```
declare @myMailServer varchar(30) = N'Select top 1 columnName from myServersTable'
select @myQuery = 'c:\folder\mailto.exe -H' + exec @myMailServer + '-U sender.sample.com -D receiver@sample.com'
```

But that doesn't seem to work

Answer (score 0):

You may wanna try the following code

```
declare @myquery varchar(max);
declare @myMailServer varchar(30);

SET @myMailServer = (Select top 1 columnName from myServersTable);

select @myQuery = 'c:\folder\mailto.exe -H' + @myMailServer + '-U sender.sample.com -D receiver@sample.com'
```

Comment: I don't think it's the part Select top 1 from myServersTable. I typed that wrong in this question but I actually have it this way Select top 1 columnName from myServersTable. I'll correct that in my question.